# Too many "and"s?

Tags: writing-style

> We’re available 24x7 and always on standby and ready to answer calls.

Are there too many "and"s in the previous sentence? Would this be better:

> We’re available 24x7 and always on standby, ready to answer calls.

Comment: I believe that falls under style not grammar.  The most typical form for a flat and'ed list is: this, that, and the other.

Comment: There's more than a hint of redundancy too.

Comment: No *ands*: 24x7 our operators are available to address all of your concerns.

Comment: @Mazura you should submit that as an answer, it is a good rewrite.

Comment: That's the culmination of an answer I *was* writing but it's all off-topic except that part and it still doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

That is better, yes. I would simply use:

> We’re available 24x7, ready to answer calls.

or

> We’re always on standby, ready to answer calls

This is because "available 24x7" and "always on standby" are redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are too many. I suggest,

We’re available 24/7, always on standby, and ready to answer calls.

Comment: We’re available 24/7, always on standby and ready to answer calls.